# Can someone please tell me what is written on this score?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I found this writing on a certain sheet music, but I can't read it:

[image: close-up of handwritten script fragment]

Can someone please tell me what this writing says, and what it means?

---

The composer is G. Donizetti, and the title of the piece is *Par le rang et par l'opulence*, it's from Act II of *La fille du régiment*.

The writting can be found on page 283 of the first edition ([IMSLP link](https://imslp.org/wiki/La_fille_du_r%C3%A9giment_(Donizetti,_Gaetano))):

[image: full page of score, showing the handwritten script fragment in context]

Comment: It does need more context, though my guess is "Vlo. so.," an abbreviation for _violino solo_ (violin only).

Comment: @AndyBonner But Violin does not play anywhere near this text. It might be Violoncello primo. But it is a bit weird, as this was definitely added using a broad tip pen rather than pencil which is suppose is what’s used for the Instrument markings.

Answer (score 13):

The handwritten script fragment says "**No. 10.**", as in *"(movement) number ten"*.

It looks like the handwritten script is just a re-organisation of the movement divisions, because a printed "№ 10" appears quite a few pages later (p. 301).  Marking a new movement at the start of snare drum solo seem like a reasonable idea.

---

To confirm this, later in the document (p. 329) we see "No. 12." in the same handwritten script, directly above the printed "№ 12":

[image: The start of the 12th movement of the score, with "No. 12" printed and handwritten (in the same script) above.]

Comment: It's odd that No. 10 is also marked again later in this score, and this aria is actually No. 9.

Comment: @Aaron Since the aria ends with rehearsal mark 20 in the original graphics, and the recitative follows, this seems to fit nicely (assuming the writing matches the score *above*.)

Comment: @guidot Maybe I misunderstood. Are you saying the marking in question actually comes at the end of the aria, rather than denoting the beginning?

Comment: Looking very carefully at the movement numbers, they *all* seem to have been added/changed after printing (by the same hand that wrote in the rehearsal marks).  It's just that the script No. 10 is the only one at a position that wasn't originally at a movement division (which is why it's been written so big and fancy).  Perhaps it'd be better to call this No. 9B.